# Codepipeline not creating new rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I am creating a new pipeline in AWS and my source is CodeCommit. But when I click on create pipeline, I get an error:

> Failed on the following Amazon CloudWatch Events operation: PutTargets. The following message contains details on the exception: The requested resource exceeds the maximum number allowed.

I know my event rule has 5/5 targets and there is a limit so the new target cannot be added.
However, I am unable to find a way to add/link new event rule associated with CodePipeline.

According to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-trigger-source-repo-changes-console.html), my rule should be automatically created but I see no pop ups or alerts.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I wonder what are the 5 targets that are attached to your rule? Maybe some other CodePIpelines are using the same rule to putTarget? Are you cloning a pipeline or creating a new one from scratch?

Comment: @Myz All targets are attached to my different pipelines. The point is that i am unable to create new rule when creating fresh pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a new pipeline through AWS console, by default, it creates a new event rule and add target(s) to that rule. Now, depending upon the source type you select in your pipeline, it can have multiple targets for that rule.

As you already mentioned, you have CodeCommit as the source in your pipeline and for one repository and one branch, you should ideally have one target for your event rule. I have experienced similar kind of issue in the past where AWS backend somehow matches the first common characters for a branch name which may result selecting multiple branches for a single repository and hence multiple targets. For example;

Your repository has this kind of structure

[image]

If you select only **DEV** branch in your CodeCommit source, it might add 3 targets in your event rule i.e. for **DEV, DEV1** and **DEV2**. I don't exactly know the reason behind this, could be a bug or perhaps intentional. My bet is on regex as the culprit here. So in your case, it could be that you have more than 5 branches that start with the name DEV and that's why it is reaching the limit, hence giving you the error.

So here's what you can try. Select the branch that is either totally unique or has some differences. In other words, select any branch other than **DEV** and see if you still get the error. If this works, it means that it's time to properly organize your repository and have proper naming convention for the branches.